how to restore wiki security menu
While managing permissions on DevOps Wiki, the Wiki Security menu is out of sight. I have permissions from the collection manager now, but I want to know what menu I need to go to manage my Wiki permissions. The current menu is as follows.

I tried to see if the menu was accessible by removing it for the rest of the permissions except the collection manager permissions. However, it was impossible to check because there were parts tied to the company management group.

Are you using On-prem DevOps server? If so, what's the version? And what's the type of the wiki, project wiki or code wiki? Please share a full screenshot of the wiki page.

I can reproduce the same wiki option after related permission removed for the account.

To get the Wiki Security menu back for your account, you can use another Project administrator account(add the account if you don't have). You can find the admin in project setting -> permissions-> project administrators group.

With this account， try to manage the wiki security, then grant contribute permission for your account.
Sample as below(the security page could be different if you are using on-prem devops server):

After it's done, login with your account, check the wiki page again, you should be able to find the Wiki Security menu now:


@youngha, the issue is caused by your account lost contribute permission on target wiki. You can follow above steps to add the permission back, then you can see the options. Let me know if you have any queries, thanks.
